# Spring non English characters not correctly inserting to mysql database

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, unicode, utf-8

My spring 3 application has a jsp page to insert non English(Sinhala) characters to the database. I have changed database column collocation to utf-8.

When I am inserting characters directly to the database, it is storing correctly as expected. But it is storing ????? when inserting though the jsp.

in my jsp page it has this line on the top of the page  <%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Do I need to do anything else to store this non english charactors correctly?

Comment: See "question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: See "Spring" in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages